# RSpec - How to test a database view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

I have a class that is backing a database view. I am using FactoryGirl to try and test this so I go through the normal steps of creating a `user` instance like so:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end
```

Then I check the view count:

```
Balance.all.count   # It is returning 0, it should be returning 1
```

My understanding of database views is that they do not update until after the transaction is committed to the database. I have a background working with NHibernate and in order to get an updated value from the database, I would do something like:

```
Session.Flush();
```

That would allow me then to query the database view and get updated values but still rollback or commit my transaction later.

Is there a way to do this in ActiveRecord? Or is there a way to commit my changes to the database and clean it up? I don't want to turn off the transactions for all tests, just be able to test this one particular class.

Comment: Why would creating an user touch the 'Balances' table?¿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }`

You may also want to look into the `database_cleaner` gem.

Comment: We used the database_cleaner gem. Was the easiest option.